# Display the times for local time (Los Angeles or Pacific) and New York with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I have a question for my homework.

If I were to display timezones from different timezone locations, how do you insert JavaScript to display the times for local time (Los Angeles or Pacific) and New York?

Comment: You can use MomentJS library http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: use this answer instruction, it's worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708555/11760150

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is **not** to implement it by hand in any way but to use a ready library. Use [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
var now = moment(); // current timestamp, using your machine's time zone
var nowLA = now.tz('America/Los_Angeles'); // converted to LA time zone
var nowNY = now.tz('America/New_York'); // converted to NY time zone
```

Then, you can print it using any of the formats provided by [Moment](http://momentjs.com/), eg.

```
now.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // September 13th 2015, 10:43:17 am
```

Comment: the `now.format(...)` returns a string, so just put that string dynamically wherever you want on your page.