# Is there an external api to get the current date/time in British Summer Time format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following javascript function, where i am getting 2 variables from our system (`expireddate` + `modifieddate`)+ i am getting the current Date, as follow:-

```
function(){ 

  var expirydate = item.get_item('ExpireDate');             
  var modifieddate = item.get_item('Modified');
  var currentdate = new Date();
```

now in my case all the variables will be in this format `Tue Jun 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`.. and i am not facing any issue since my pc is also using the `(British Summer Time)` date, so the `var currentdate = new Date();` will be compatible with other formats... but my question is how i can guarantee that `var currentdate = new Date();` will always be in the `(British Summer Time)` date regardless of the users' PCs settings? so if the user is using another date format, to have the `var currentdate = new Date();` in `(British Summer Time)` date format ? can i for example get the current date from external source?

Comment: Not exactly the same but this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707902/working-with-different-timezones-in-javascript

Comment: http://momentjs.com/  http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @jmoerdyk can you advice more on this ? how i can get a consistent Date() using those libraries?

Comment: Use ISO 8601 formatted date / time strings so there's zero ambiguity, eg `2019-06-11T00:00:00+01:00`

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are looking for, and if so, you will want to use [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), and tell it what format you would like the result to be in.

The following will result in british time format in the UTC timezone.

```js
let date = new Date()

console.log('UTC:', date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }))
console.log('Guernsey:', date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/Guernsey' }))
console.log('Guernsey Time:', date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/Guernsey' }))
```

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. so this will work regardless of the user' PCs regional settings and date/time format such as `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: It should, I am nowhere near that location, and for me it displays the time of **Guernsey** as `01:49:21`